# Pass parameter from parent to child through third-party component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

Is it possible to pass a function defined in **Component1**(only inside this component, not in any other) to **Component2** as a property?

If there hasn't been **Route** component I would use  ***React.cloneElement*** method.

**Route** could be used only inside **MainComponent** definition.

```
class MainComponent extends React.Component {
render() {
 return (
   <Component1>
     <Route
       path={match.url + '/myUrl'}
       render={() => (
         <Component2 />
       )}
     />
   </Component1>
  )
 }
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you elaborate? What is the function you're trying to pass? It seems like you simply want to pass a function as a [prop](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/props.html) to `Component2`.

Comment: Actually I need to call method in child from parent. But it's irrelevant for this question. And yes, I need to pass function as a prop.

Comment: Can you put the Component1 inside the render too?

Comment: nope, the problem is I cannot change components order

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like:

```
class MainComponent extends React.Component {
  callComponent1func = (...params) => {
    if(this.component1Ref && typeof this.component1Ref.component1func === "function"){
      this.component1Ref.component1func(...params);
    }
  };

  render() {
   return (
     <Component1 ref={(element) => this.component1Ref = element}>
       <Route
         path={match.url + '/myUrl'}
         render={() => (
           <Component2 component1func={this.callComponent1func}/>
         )}
       />
     </Component1>
    )
  }
}
```

Here function `callComponent1func` is passed as a prop to `Component2` and when it's called it accesses `Component1` via ref and calls it's function. Hence achieving your use-case.

Answer (score 1):

Define a prop in `Component2` with your function :)

```
class Component1 extends React.Component {
  callback = () => doSomething()

  render() {
    return (
      <Route
        path={match.url + '/myUrl'}
        render={() => <Component2 callback={this.callback} />}
      />
    )
  }
}


function Component2({ callback }) {
  myFunc();
}
```

Comment: myFunc has to be defined inside Component1

Answer (score 0):

So in component 1:

```
import { Route, BrowserRouter} from 'react-router';
class Component1 extends React.Component {
  myFunc(){
    }

  render() {
    return (
      <BrowserRouter>
      <Route
        path={match.url + '/myUrl'}
        render={() => <Component2 callback={this.myFunc} />}
      />
      </BrowserRouter>
    )
  }
}
```

And in component 2 you can call the function from props using `props.muFunc`

Comment: Can you elaborate ?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this?

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

const A = () => {
  const woof = () => {
    alert("Woof!");
  };

  return <B woof={woof} />;
};

const B = ({ woof }) => {
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <h1>Woofatron</h1>
      <button onClick={woof}>click me </button>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
};

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<A />, rootElement);
```

Working example [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/9yyvv57z9w).

Comment: The first example doesn't use Route?

Comment: without Route or any other third-party component it just doesn't make sence

Comment: I don't understand – do you want to use a Route: yes or no?

Comment: yep, I need Route between A and B

Comment: and also cannot use Route inside A or B definition

Comment: Okay, I don't understand.